# I wanted to give back

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> When I sold my company, Aviato, I wanted to give back, that's why I started this place.

I checked the meanings of [give back](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnlZTHocfVAhUK6WMKHVJdD80QFgg2MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macmillandictionary.com%2Fus%2Fdictionary%2Famerican%2Fgive-back&usg=AFQjCNFwpreo_1HsQW6GxlpGoQQEydNpjQ) and none matched this.

Does "give back" in this sentence mean
1) helping novices as a kind of charity?
2) Investing in a new business?
3) Starting off once again and more strongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the context of "This place"?

Usually "give back" is used in the context of "Giving back to the people, as a charity"

Answer (score 1):

"give back" in this kind of context is almost always used in reference to charity.

Specifically, the sentence you give could be more clearly conveyed like so:

"When I sold my company, Aviato, I wanted to give back to the community. That's why I started this place."